# Pyinstaller throws AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to turn a Python app (with a PyQt dialog) into an exe using pyinstaller. Unfortunately this doesn't work and returns the following output to the console:

There's only one (!) Python script, app.py. It contains some functions and a class for the gui. Nothing special.

```
C:\Users\m14\Desktop\PythonApp>pyinstaller --onefile app.py
1595 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.13.0
1597 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
1597 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
1598 INFO: wrote C:\Users\m14\Desktop\PythonApp\app.spec
1606 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\m14\\Desktop\\PythonApp']
2777 INFO: checking Analysis
2779 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
2779 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
2790 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
2899 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5226 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5403 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6438 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9095 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
9287 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
9304 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
9872 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\m14\Desktop\PythonApp\app.py
11131 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
11583 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11584 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12124 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12566 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
13816 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-docx.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
15648 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
15937 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.uic.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
16317 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook PyQt5.uic.port_v2 from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-PyQt5.uic.port_v2.py'.
16681 INFO: Processing module hooks...
16681 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
16938 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
18560 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19896 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.isoschematron.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
19920 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
19920 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
20126 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
20312 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
20431 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.objectify.py' from 'C:\\Users\\m14\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 194, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1019, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 944, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\m14\Desktop\PythonApp\app.spec", line 20, in <module>
    noarchive=False,
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 429, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 599, in assemble
    deps_proc = DependencyProcessor(self.graph, self.graph._additional_files_cache)
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\toc_conversion.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._distributions.update(self._get_distribution_for_node(node))
  File "C:\Users\m14\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\toc_conversion.py", line 88, in _get_distribution_for_node
    assert len(dists) == 1
AssertionError

C:\Users\m14\Desktop\PythonApp>
```

Any idea?

Comment: what version of python do you use ?

Comment: you have to use the newest version of python because pyinstaller has a lot of problems in versions under 3.8

Comment: If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it as a solution for this problem. Updating to 3.11.5 solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: pleasure to help you ..  i did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem sometimes it is in the version of the python that you are using

pyinstaller faces a lot of problems in python versions those are under 3.8.

and to solve your problem you have to install the newest version of python.